# Jquery Jstree get checked checkbox atrribute onclick event

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick, jstree

I am using jstree and populating the data using JSON. Now i would like to capture event of each node when it checked.

```
$("#" +newTreeDiv).bind("check_node.jstree", function (e, d) {
     var tagName = d.args[0].tagName;
     var refreshing = d.inst.data.core.refreshing;
     if ((tagName == "A" || tagName == "INS") &&
     (refreshing != true && refreshing != "undefined")) {
       alert(d.inst.get_checked().attr('path'));
     }
});
```

In the above case, if i select two nodes it always gives the attributes of first node. e.g. Refer to the below image, if i try to select 'tags' or 'trunk' it always gives me the attributes of 'branches' which i have selected at the beginning.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling around in the internet i found my answer.

actually to get the checked items attribute we have to use

> d.inst.get_checked().attr('path');

And to get only the clicked element's attribute we have to use

```
d.rslt.obj.attr('path');
```